# SQL join by timestamp diff

Tags: plsql

Given the below table(events) I want to do a inner join by comparing the timestamp difference on the TIMESTAMP_CREATE field

| EVENT_ID | TIMESTAMP_CREATE |
| --- | --- |
| 47038506 | 04-DEC-20 05.21.45.559496 PM |
| 47038290 | 04-DEC-20 05.21.45.076845 PM |
| 47038077 | 04-DEC-20 05.21.13.508805 PM |
| 47038027 | 04-DEC-20 05.21.13.480446 PM |

For example.

```
SELECT x.EVENT_ID AS x_event_id
    ,x.TIMESTAMP_CREATE AS x_timestamp_create
    ,y.EVENT_ID AS y_event_id
    ,y.TIMESTAMP_CREATE AS y_timestamp_create
FROM events x
INNER JOIN events y 
ON x.TIMESTAMP_CREATE - y.TIMESTAMP_CREATE = min(x.TIMESTAMP_CREATE - y.TIMESTAMP_CREATE FOR ALL rows IN events)
```

I want the output as below :

```
+------------+------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+
| x_event_id | x_timestamp_create           | y_event_id | y_timestamp_create           |
+------------+------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+
| 47038506   | 04-DEC-20 05.21.45.559496 PM | 47038290   | 04-DEC-20 05.21.45.076845 PM |
| 47038077   | 04-DEC-20 05.21.13.508805 PM | 47038027   | 04-DEC-20 05.21.13.480446 PM |
+------------+------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+
```

Precisely, I am trying to match-up the events in a join operation so that two events which have the least difference in `timestamp_create` field appear in the same row as in the output above,
how can I achieve this using Oracle PL/SQL joins ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle, SQL Server etc.,?

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: What if 3 events falls on the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you prefer you prefer to show in the same line previous event
(that is a guess, as it does not match completely your output).
If that is the case, assuming event_id grows monotonically in time, you can have result in SQL.

Preparation:

```
create table events (event_id number, timestamp_create timestamp(6)); 

insert into events values ( 47038506, to_timestamp('04-DEC-20 05.21.45.559496 PM', 'dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff6 AM') );
insert into events values ( 47038290, to_timestamp('04-DEC-20 05.21.45.076845 PM', 'dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff6 AM') );
insert into events values ( 47038077, to_timestamp('04-DEC-20 05.21.13.508805 PM', 'dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff6 AM') );
insert into events values ( 47038027, to_timestamp('04-DEC-20 05.21.13.480446 PM', 'dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff6 AM') );
```

Run (edited after comment):

```
select 
  next_event_id, next_timestamp_create, 
  event_id, timestamp_create
from 
( select 
  event_id, 
  timestamp_create, 
  lag(event_id) over (order by event_id) last_event_id, 
  lag(timestamp_create) over (order by event_id)         
  last_timestamp_create, 
  lead(event_id) over (order by event_id) next_event_id, 
  lead(timestamp_create) over (order by event_id) next_timestamp_create 
from
  events
  order by event_id
)
where next_timestamp_create - timestamp_create < timestamp_create - last_timestamp_create
or last_timestamp_create is null 
;
```

Hint: It is easier to handle and maintain if expressed in SQL query instead of PL/SQL. And it would perform much better.

Fiddle is available on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d8dc/20

Comment: No, I am not trying to put the last event on the same line, but I am trying to match-up the events in a join operation so that two events which have the least difference in timestamp_create field, ill be put on the same line.

Comment: @amitmula query changed to verify closest lines